# Display Webpage current URL with Firefox extension

Tags: javascript, url, firefox-addon

I've written the following code for the purpose of the title of the post but instead of having the real URL I get the previous URL (e.g. If I'm on Google and type "car" in the search field and type "Enter" I get "http://www.google.fr" and not the URL from the search).

code :

```
window.addEventListener("change", function() { myExtension_with_change.init(); }, false);

var myExtension_with_change = {
   init: function() {
       var url = window.location.href;
       alert(url);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In another post https://stackoverflow.com/users/785541/wladimir-palant gave a perfect answer ( [Get URL of a webpage dynamically with Javascript on a Firefox extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6451678/get-url-of-a-webpage-dynamically-with-javascript-on-a-firefox-extension) ) .

Answer (score 0):

You might need to add an event listener inside the first to wait for the window to load, such as:

```
window.addEventListener("change", function()
{

   window.addEventListener("load", function()
   {

       myExtension_with_change.init();

   }, false);

}, false);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I've tried it and no alert is displayed now.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that window is the correct anchor to listen for changes of the URL. My first try would be listen to change events at #urlbar (I didn't try that, though):

```
window.getElementById('#urlbar').addEventListener("change", function() {    
    myExtension_with_change.init(); }, false);
```

If your ultimate goal is to listen to URL changes on every tab I suggest you also have look at the [Tabbed Browser documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets/Tabbed_browser) and this [code snippet on location changes](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Listening_to_events_on_all_tabs).

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I've tried it and no alert is displayed now.

Comment: @Bruno: That's probably because it should be `document.getElementById('urlbar')` and not `window.getElementById('#urlbar')`.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I followed the recommendation in http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=194671. Simply calling the following code snippet gives me the current url

> gBrowser.mCurrentBrowser.currentURI.QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIURI);
>   var currentUrl = gBrowser.mCurrentBrowser.currentURI.spec;